# Open file in perl and STDERR contents problems

Tags: perl, unit-testing, file-upload

I'm trying to write some unit tests for a perl file uploading script.  I'm still pretty new to  perl so I'm having some issues achieving the outcome I expect from my code.

Basically my thought process is that I can pass a test_only attribute along with the request that will tell the script to just grab a file already on the system rather than try to use an uploaded file.

I created a test file and put it in my output/tmp directory.  I made sure to set its permissions to 775.  Its just a simple .txt file that says "I am a test file".

What I expect to happen currently is that when I run my test script I should see the contents of the file printed out to the error log as well as some reference to the buffer(so I can verify the file is being opened properly).  However, this is not happening, nothing is being put in the error log.  I'm wondering if the file is being opened properly?

I'm sure I'm just missing something fundamental about how perl opens files.  Any help will be appreciated.  Thanks :)

This is the appropriate snippet of my code:

```
my $test_only = 1;
my $tmp_uploads_path = "/home/my_instance/output/tmp/";
if($test_only)
{
    #put simulated file handle and file name here
    $file = "";
    $file_name = "test_file.txt";
}
else
{

    $file = $q->upload('file') 
        || die "No file data sent\n $!";

    $file_name = $q->param('file_name') 
        || die "No file_name sent\n $!";
}

########
#SAVE THE UPLOAD
########
my $bufsize = 1024;    
my $buffer = '';

open(my $TMPFILE, ">".$tmp_uploads_path.$file_name);
binmode $TMPFILE;
print STDERR "=> ".Dumper($TMPFILE)."\n";
while(read ($TMPFILE, $buffer, $bufsize)){
    print STDERR "=> ".Dumper($TMPFILE)."\n";
    print STDERR "=> ".Dumper($buffer)."\n";
    print $TMPFILE $buffer;    
}
close($TMPFILE);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You opened the `$TMPFILE` for writing, due to the `>` mode. Therefore, you cannot read from it.

You should always put `use strict; use warnings;` at the top of your scripts, this would have alerted you to this problem!

You should open files like

```
my $name = ...;
open my $fh, "<", $name or die "Can't open $name: $!";
```

or

```
use autodie;
open my $fh, "<", $name;
```

That is, do proper error handling, and use the three-arg variant of `open`: handle, mode and name (don't concat mode and name, except on ancient perls).

I am also suprised that you are using `read`. You can get a similar effect by

```
local $/ = \$bufsize;
while (defined(my $buffer = <$TMPFILE>)) { ... }
```

Comment: thanks for your help.  This answer got me there.  I'm actually writing tests for a new API to this code, so I'm not surprised that there are some older standards being used.